# How to print maximum value of a specific row/column in numpy array?

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix, max, min

```
#input

import numpy as np
arr = np.array([(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8),(9,10,11,12)])
print(arr)
print(np.max(arr))
print(np.max(arr,0))
print(np.max(arr,1))

#output

[[ 1  2  3  4]
[ 5  6  7  8]
[ 9 10 11 12]]
 12
[ 9 10 11 12]
[ 4  8 12]
```

I am getting the max value of the whole matrix, max value of all rows, and columns but how can I get the maximum value of a certain row to suppose I want to print the max value of only row 1 (i.e 8) not of each and every row.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

if

```
np.max(arr, 1)
```

gives you the maximum of each row:

```
[ 4  8 12]
```

you can simply use:

```
np.max(arr, 1)[i]
```

to get the max value of row i

or alternatively:

```
np.max(arr[i])
```